# How to fetch data from mysql database using array dataset

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to fetch data from mysql database and php codeigniter using the data i already have in an array. but it seems am doing something wrong.

```
 $query = $this->db->query("select * from product_order where transaction_code='BfkA'");
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
            {   
                $p_id = $row['product_id'];
                $this->db->join('product_order', 'product_order.product_id = products.product_id');
                $this->db->where('products.product_id', $p_id);
                $res=$this->db->get('products');
            }
                return $res->result_array();
```

I want the output to be like this in my table

```
<table border="1">
<tr> <td>Product Name</td> <td>Quantity</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>shoe</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>bag</td> <td>4</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>watch</td> <td>3</td> </tr>
</table> 

but i get

<table border="1">
<tr> <td>Product Name</td> <td>Quantity</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>shoe</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>shoe</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `where_in` to replace the `where` method and use `array_column` to get the *product_id* array, then you could remove the `foreach` block :

```
$query = $this->db->query("select product_id from product_order where transaction_code='BfkA'");
$prod_ids = array_column($query->result_array(), 'product_id');

$this->db->join('product_order', 'product_order.product_id = products.product_id');
$this->db->where_in('products.product_id', $prod_ids);
$res = $this->db->get('products');
return $res->result_array();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. but this isn't what am looking for

Comment: Maybe you have a wrong view too? your query is surely wrong, you are overwriting the `$res` on each iteration, so at the end it will just return one result from the last iteration

Comment: Yes. I guess so. changing it now will affect other areas of my code. am just trying to see how i can manipulate this to work well without having to touch other areas.